# How to run delayed_jobs in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I am using delayed_job in rails application development and in development environment i use `bin/delayed_job start`

But how to do the same in production environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

This should make the delayed jobs run in production env

Comment: I was really stuck here.. Thanks... A quick solution

Comment: This gives me permission error - -bash: `bin/delayed_job: Permission denied`. Using Centos for production. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you in the rails project directory when calling this?

Answer (score 1):

To start:

```
cd /home/user/app;
bundle exec /usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /home/user/app/script/delayed_job start
```

To stop:

```
cd /home/user/app; 
bundle exec /usr/bin/env RAILS_ENV=production /home/user/app/script/delayed_job stop
```

Refer to official documentation at [github](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#user-content-running-jobs).

```
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Runs two workers in separate processes.
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -n 2 start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job stop

# Set the --queue or --queues option to work from a particular queue.
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queue=tracking start
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --queues=mailers,tasks start

# Use the --pool option to specify a worker pool. You can use this option multiple times to start different numbers of workers for different queues.
# The following command will start 1 worker for the tracking queue,
# 2 workers for the mailers and tasks queues, and 2 workers for any jobs:
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job --pool=tracking --pool=mailers,tasks:2 --pool=*:2 start

# Runs all available jobs and then exits
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start --exit-on-complete
# or to run in the foreground
RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job run --exit-on-complete
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else gets stuck with -bash: bin/delayed_job: Permission denied error as Disha did in comments above, for Centos it is enough to set delayed_job in bin/ folder in your project's directory to executable.